# How to load multiple shapefile of point and convert it into csv file in loops?

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, shapefile

I want to read and convert multiple shapefile into csv. The link contain sample of shapefile. Following is the code I was trying.

```
  library(raster)
  setwd("D:/share_1/PAPER_regimes/22_06_22/hp/firepoint_12_veg")
  all.files <- list.files(pattern="\\.shp$")
  out.files <- gsub("\\.shp$", ".csv")
  crs <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
  for(i in 1:length(all.files)) {
   d <- readOGR(all.files[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = d[c("Longitude", "Latitude")], d, proj4string = crs) 
   utm <- spTransform(sp, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84"))
   shapefile(utm, out.files[i])
    }
```

[link contain few shapefile and dataset which are in point](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IOKr62NR40LwELo7u9_YFeeC7eLzAKGq?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1) Ok, great, so what is the problem/error/missing piece?  2) for easier data conversion i recommend using the `sf` package to read in your shapefile (instead of  `raster` / `sp`).  3) maybe look at the apply/lapply family of functions to streamline & speed up your process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this

```
library(terra)
all.files <- list.files(pattern="\\.shp$", full=TRUE)
out.files <- gsub("\\.shp$", ".csv", all.files)

for(i in 1:length(all.files)) {
   d <- vect(all.files[i])
   utm <- project(d, "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84")
   xy <- crds(utm)
   write.csv(xy, out.files[i], row.names=FALSE)
}
```

I do not know why you went to the lon/lat in the attributes, but if that is what you need you can do:

```
for(i in 1:length(all.files)) {
   d <- vect(all.files[i])
   geo <- vect(data.frame(d), c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), crs="+proj=longlat")
   utm <- project(d, "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84")
   xy <- crds(utm)
   write.csv(xy, out.files[i], row.names=FALSE)
}
```